# Best way to change DateTime.now across all places

Tags: c#

I got a requirement that wherever we have DateTime.Now check it should be checked with the simulated date(from UI - accessible in test environments only), how should I design this functionality with minimum change.
Is it possible to override DateTime.Now functionality and wherever DateTime.Now is being used it will read the overriden value.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, stop using `DateTime.Now` directly. Instead, introduce an abstraction of a clock (I typically call it `IClock`) that has a single operation of "get the current date and time" and inject that everywhere, just like any other dependency.

You can then use a simple implementation that delegates to `DateTime.Now` (or better, `DateTime.UtcNow`, I'd suggest) for production, and a fake implementation for testing.

That's the approach we strongly encourage in my [NodaTime library](https://nodatime.org) - where we provide the interface *and* production/fake implementations for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be looking to design this functionality with minimum change. You should be doing things right.  Doing things right is having a "Clock" interface (or "IClock" in dot net parlance) and passing it around (injecting it, service-locating it, manually propagating it, whatever it takes) to every place that needs it.  Do it right, or do it twice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to override `DateTime.Now` functionality

No. `DateTime.Now` is a static property - there's no way to override or alter its behavior. The best you can hope for is to somehow change the system clock to match the input date/time (which may have other undesired consequences).

One option is to do a manual find/replace to wrap the DateTime.Now calls in an interface that can be mocked. You could also look ad code analysis tools to detect usages going forward.